# determine the width of bold text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, tikz-decorations

In [bold tikz text decoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499106/bold-tikz-text-decoration) `|\bf|` was mentioned as a possible way to insert a bolt tikz text decoration.

How to determine the width of a bold tikz text decoration?

I try:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % ...                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("Some text")}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthb}{width("|\bf|Some bold text")}
  %...                                                                                                                                                                                                      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The compilation encounters an error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.7 ...ro{\mywidthb}{width("|\bf|Some bold text")}
```

The application of the width will be as in [centre text exactly on an exactly specified point on path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497377/centre-text-exactly-on-an-exactly-specified-point-on-path?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: You can do `\protected\def\mybold{\bfseries}` and then `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthb}{width("|\mybod|Some bold text")}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this work by patching `\pgfmathparse`.  You have to replace two `\edef` by `\protected@edef`.  The following works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\def\pgfmathparse@#1{%
    % No (math) units yet.
    \global\pgfmathunitsdeclaredfalse
    \global\pgfmathmathunitsdeclaredfalse
    % Expand expression so any remaining CSs are registers
    % or box dimensions (i.e. |\wd|, |\ht|, |\dp|).
    \protected@edef\pgfmath@expression{#1}%
    %
    \expandafter\pgfmathparse@trynumber@loop\pgfmath@expression\pgfmath@parse@stop
    %
    % this here is the _real_ parser. it is invoked by
    % \pgfmathparse@trynumber@loop if that says "this is no number"
    %\pgfmathparse@@\pgfmath@parse@stop%
}

\def\pgfmath@startgroup@#1{\protected@edef\pgfmathresult{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("Some text")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthb}{width("|\bf|Some bold text")}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If it doesn't break the manual, it might go in the next release.

Comment: Tests pass. Here you go https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/9d18b41cee43d7f2382b6fc003e446ba3707d82e

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `"|\bf|Some bold text"` should, when used in `decorations.text` really be `"|\bfseries|Some bold text"`, see [this thread for more information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/121799), but as you point out neither of them work here. Even worse, the usual `\setbox0\hbox{...}` trick does not work since Ti*k*Z gobbles text, see e.g. [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459853/121799), from which I construct a possible solution: interrupt the `tikzpicture`, measure, resume the `tikzpicture`. Of course one could use a different syntax and so on.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfInTikzPic}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121309/4301
  \ifx\pgfpictureid\@undefined
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother
% cf https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459858/121799
\newcommand{\WidthOfStuff}[1]{\IfInTikzPic{\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
\xdef\pgfmathresult{\the\wd0}%
\end{pgfinterruptpicture}}{%
\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
\xdef\pgfmathresult{\the\wd0}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % ...                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("Some text")}
  \WidthOfStuff{\textbf{Some bold text}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthb}{\pgfmathresult}     

  \node{\mywidth,\mywidthb};
  %...                                                                                                                                                                                                      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tikz manual 3.1.3 on page 648 states that `\bf` can be used and gives an example of its use. I quote this page: *It is possible to format the text using normal formatting commands, such as `\it`, `\bf` and `\color`, within customizable delimiters.*

Comment: @AndréC Please read [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499106/bold-tikz-text-decoration#comment1260553_499106). If you do not know these things, that's bad enough, but can happen. I didn't know that, too, until some years back. But the way you present the lack of knowledge in comments may be a reason for concern.

Comment: I would like to believe that Phelype Oleinik is right. But like any scientist, I never take anyone's word for it. Is there an official source from the LaTeX core development team confirming Phelype's statement?

Comment: @AndréC Scientists depend on academic honesty... But yes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/121799.

Comment: I don't understand your remark about academic honesty.
Joseph Wright pointed out that these commands are supported. And moreover, `TikZ` is written entirely in `Plain TEX`, its source code is located in the `tex/generic/pgf` folder like all programs written in `TeX` and not in `LaTeX`. `Pgf-tikz` can be compiled into `Plain TeX`.

Comment: @AndréC Discussing with you is a pain. Is the OP's code plain TeX, yes or no? You asked why I say that one should use `\bfseries`, and I gave you several reasons. If *you* do not want to look at them, this is your private choice. But please do not add these spam-like comments on posts that attempt to solve problems.

Comment: @AndréC LaTeX2e does *not* define `\bf`, `\it`, etc. in the format.  The standard classes `article`, `report`, etc. define `\bf`, `\it`, etc. but they are not part of the kernel.

Comment: @marmot Inside a picture TikZ switches to `\nullfont`, but you can simply do `\hbox{\selectfont...}` to temporarily switch to a normal font.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, that is exactly what Joseph Wright said here [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/121799) and I quote: *The `\it` syntax is inherited from `LaTeX 2.09`, and is regarded as supported for historical reasons only in `LaTeX2e`. For bold, you should go for `\textbf` rather than `\bf`.* He doesn't mention the need to use `\bfseries`. So what about this?

Comment: @AndréC Because the “LaTeX  way” is passing arguments, e.g. `\frac{a}{b}` instead of `{a \over b}` and therefore `\texbf{...}` instead of `{\bfseries ...}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Okay, the way to pass the arguments is not the same. As a TikZ developer, how do you explain that both syntaxes work?   Is there an advantage or disadvantage to using one syntax instead of the other?

Comment: @AndréC Try `\bf\it` and `\bfseries\itshape`. What is the expected output and what do these two output?  On top of that `\bf`, `\it`, etc. mess with math families which comes with its own set of problem.

Comment: @HenriMenke After various attempts, I note that the syntax `\it\bf` does **not** put the text in italics. Similarly, `\bf\it` does **not** put the text in bold while `\itshape\bfseries` and `\bfseries\itshape` put the text in **italics and bold**. Thus, I conclude that the new syntax is more flexible for text formatting. Thank you for your clear explanations.

Comment: @AndréC Well, this is all discussed at length under https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/121799...

Comment: @marmot This does not prevent the syntax `\bf` is allowed with TikZ despite its lack of flexibility.

Comment: @HenriMenke Is there a specific order to the formatting of the text? In other words, can we write `\footnotesize\bfseries\itshape` as well as `\bfseries\footnotesize\itshape` or are there rules to follow in the successive call of these macros?